# Getting wrong distance between locations in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocationdistance

Hi aim using following method to find out the distance between my current location and the locations(lat and longitude) stored in NSMutableArray value.

But am getting wrong distance..Please help..

My code

```
    -(void)getDistancetoShow:(NSMutableArray *)newArray{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateUser = [self getLocation];


    float _lat,_long;


  first_Loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinateUser.latitude longitude:coordinateUser.longitude];

    for(int p=0;p<[[newArray1 valueForKey:@"Name"] count];p++){

        _lat=[[[newArray1 valueForKey:@"Latitude"] objectAtIndex:p]floatValue];
         _long=[[[newArray1 valueForKey:@"Longitude"] objectAtIndex:p]floatValue];
        second_loc=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:_lat longitude:_long];


        showDistance=[second_loc distanceFromLocation:first_Loc]/1000;

        [distanceToDispaly addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f KM",showDistance]];
    }

     NSLog(@"first=%@, second=%@", first_Loc, second_loc);


}
```

Latitudes in array

(
    "47.0735010448824",
    "47.0564688100431",
    " 47.0582514311038",
    "47.0587640538326",
    "47.0569233603454",
    "47.0541853132569",
    "47.0542029215138",
    "47.0544259594592",
    "47.0560264547367",
    " 47.0576532159776",
    " 47.0550023679218",
    "47.0342030007379",
    "47.0746263896213",
    " 47.0740256635512",
    "47.0524765957921",
    "47.0606287049051",
    "47.0539691521825",
    "47.0542799159057",
    "47.0651001682846",
    "47.0536948902097",
    "47.0525973335309",
    "47.0389265414812",
    "47.0761811267051",
    "47.0668801601942",
    "47.0614859079241",
    "47.0579433468181",
    "47.0718998779465"
)

and longitude in array

(
    "21.9154175327011",
    "21.9312065669748",
    "21.9337414545594",
    " 21.9346772505188",
    " 21.9300587945685",
    "21.9363460105132",
    "21.9362081709222",
    "21.9343042603097",
    "21.939485335992",
    "21.9320057169724",
    "21.9300799002643",
    "21.9485373571669",
    "21.9310667367526",
    "21.9318507902135",
    "21.9192195298473",
    "21.9195273899529",
    "21.9329595191441",
    "21.9292015418841",
    "21.9219452321208",
    "21.9098849252041",
    "21.9074768948561",
    "21.9424499491422",
    "21.9151458954504",
    "21.9304346568769",
    "21.9305973807911",
    "21.9331511189507",
    "21.9159872752442"
)

but the real distance in something like staring with 9**********  but am getiing now 5*******

Comment: Do you run your app in simulator? Simulator can't show your current location

Comment: What is the value of `first_Loc`? Without that information, it is impossible to check your results.

Comment: my lat and long 12.975602--77.638898

Comment: Have you *verified* that `first_loc` contains what you expect? - When I compute the distance from `first_loc = (12.975602,-77.638898)` to `second_loc = (47.0735010448824, 21.9154175327011)` with `[second_loc distanceFromLocation: first_loc]` then the result is 9656643.489674237.

Comment: yes..but when iam trying using following code am getting like 5623.222KM

Comment: can u please check my above code that,if any mistakes in that code ?

Comment: @user2990885: Can you please add `NSLog(@"first=%@, second=%@", first_loc, second_loc);` to your code and show the output (only the output for the first calculated distance) ?

Comment: first=<+12.97561040,+77.63890489> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 27/01/14 4:46:18 pm India Standard Time, second=<+47.06212234,+21.92973518> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 27/01/14 4:46:18 pm India Standard Time

Comment: @user2990885: The distance from <+12.97561040,+77.63890489> to <+47.06212234,+21.92973518>, calculated with distanceFromLocation:, is  6382278.067965 meter = 6382 km. I get (almost) the same result with the online calculator http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml. So why do you think the result should be 9*** ? Perhaps you mixed up east/west longitude somewhere?

Comment: how i sthat possible??? try bangalore to romania distance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

Comment: @Jave: It is not a duplicate of that question. As you can see, OP is using the proper method `distanceFromLocation:` to calculate the distance.

Comment: @user2990885: Please tell us what result you exactly expand *AND WHY*. At present we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Martin my problem was that distance ,Actually am confused which is correct 9625KM  or 6382KM thats my problem

Comment: @user2990885: Why 9625KM? How did you calculate that value? Can you explain that in a way that somebody else can reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

CLLocation gives you crow(straight) distance between two places. I thinks you are getting crow distance.

First take coordinate of two places and find distance between them.
then search crow distance between those two coordinate.

hope this will help

Comment: exact distance is like 96222.00 but it showing only 56232.00 etc

Comment: ok first you should give the hard coded coordinate of two point
Take two CLLocation variable and apply 

distanceFromPlayerToEnemySelectedInMeters = [enemyLocation distanceFromLocation:playerLocation];

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the two coordinates you can calculate the distance between them using this piece of code (taken from [here](http://hayageek.com/ios-geofencing-api/)):

```
- (NSNumber*)calculateDistanceInMetersBetweenCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord1 coord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord2 {
    NSInteger nRadius = 6371; // Earth's radius in Kilometers
    double latDiff = (coord2.latitude - coord1.latitude) * (M_PI/180);
    double lonDiff = (coord2.longitude - coord1.longitude) * (M_PI/180);
    double lat1InRadians = coord1.latitude * (M_PI/180);
    double lat2InRadians = coord2.latitude * (M_PI/180);
    double nA = pow ( sin(latDiff/2), 2 ) + cos(lat1InRadians) * cos(lat2InRadians) * pow ( sin(lonDiff/2), 2 );
    double nC = 2 * atan2( sqrt(nA), sqrt( 1 - nA ));
    double nD = nRadius * nC;
    // convert to meters
    return @(nD*1000);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: CLLocation has a method named `distanceFromLocation:` returns distance in meter

Comment: How do you know the real distance?

Comment: i searched in google it showing distance is 9621KM and iam getting only 5646509.944427(in meter)   . When i first implemented my code it was showing like  9621212.245445(meter) but i tried to divide with 1000.after that i removed that diving part but still it giving wrong value

Comment: Remark: I don't know how `distanceFromLocation:` computes the distance, but the "Haversine Formula" (which is what your `calculateDistanceInMetersBetweenCoord:` uses) cannot be precise for all locations on the earth, because the radius of the earth is not constant.

Comment: @MartinR you're correct. Since this is not my code I didn't realise this method has a potential inaccuracy of up to 0.5%. +1

Answer (score 0):

To get distance from array of points in `Swift` use below reduce method.

Here `locations` is array of type `CLLocation`.

```
 let calculatedDistance = locations.reduce((0, locations[0])) { ($0.0 + $0.1.distance(from: $1), $1)}.0
```